# Putting array from database into PHP/HTML Table

Tags: php, html, arrays, database, pdo

I can't seem to get my array into an HTML/PHP table, EDIT: the table is just empty

Here is the code for the table:

```
       <?php
       include ('CarsDb.class.php');
       $db = new CarsDb();
       $db->connect();
       $db->select($array);
       var_dump($array);        

    ?>
    <h1 align="center">Database of Cars.</h1>
    <form method="POST" >
        <table class="sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="makehead">Make </th>
                    <th id="modelhead">Model </th>
                    <th id="idhead">Delete </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $i = 0;
                foreach($db->select($array)->fetchAll as $row){
                    $i++;
                    echo '<tr>';
                    if ($i % 2) {
                        echo '<td class="make">' . $row['make'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="model">' . $row['model'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="id"><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';   
                    } else {
                        echo '<td class="makelight">' . $row['make'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="modellight">' . $row['model'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="idlight"><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';                           
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
            <td>
                <input Onclick="return ConfirmDelete();" name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></input>
            </td>
        </table></form>
```

It gets its data from a function within a class and here is the class:

```
    public function select($array) {
    try {

        $result ="SELECT id,make,model FROM cars";

        $stmt = $this->db->query($result);
        $array = $stmt->fetchAll();
        var_dump($array);


    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

When I use var_dump it is showing me the array but I can't figure out how to get it in the table, fairly new to this but the array shows this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(2) "27" [0]=> string(2) "27" ["make"]=> string(7) "McLaren" [1]=> string(7) "McLaren" ["model"]=> string(2) "P1" [2]=> string(2) "P1" } [1]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(2) "28" [0]=> string(2) "28" ["make"]=> string(7) "McLaren" [1]=> string(7) "McLaren" ["model"]=> string(7) "MP4-12C" [2]=> string(7) "MP4-12C" } [2]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(2) "29" [0]=> string(2) "29" ["make"]=> string(6) "Nissan" [1]=> string(6) "Nissan" ["model"]=> string(3) "GTR" [2]=> string(3) "GTR" } }
```

Comment: whats the error? Wrong data? empty table ??

Comment: Empty table @Kisaragi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "empty table" you mean your html table is blank, this is a `foreach` loop you can use:

```
$carArray= array(0 => array("id" => "27", "make" => "McLaren", "model" => "P1"),
1=> array ( "id"=> "28", "make"=> "McLaren", "model"=> "MP4-12C"), 
2=> array ( "id"=> "29", "make"=> "Nissan", "model"=> "GTR"));

$i=0;
echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr><td>id</td><td>make</td><td>P1</td></tr>";
foreach($carArray as $k => $carInfo){
    $i++;
    echo '<tr>';
    if ($i % 2) {
        echo '<td class="make">' . $carInfo['make'] . '</td>
        <td class="model">' . $carInfo['model'] . '</td>
        <td class="id"><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="' . $carInfo['id'] . '">' . $carInfo['id'] . '</td>';   
    }
    else {
        echo '<td class="makelight">' . $carInfo['make'] . '</td>
        <td class="modellight">' . $carInfo['model'] . '</td>
        <td class="idlight"><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="' . $carInfo['id'] . '">' . $carInfo['id'] . '</td>';                           
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

I renamed your array for testing purposes and included it at the top so you can do some quick work on it but this should be everything you need.

Comment: thank you, this works well if I use the array that you've got at the top however it still won't get the database array from my select function in my class, do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: What happens when you take the name of my array `$carArr` and change it to `$array` and then run this loop inside of your code?

Comment: Thanks for the help I've got it fixed now, I just assigned $carArray to £db->select